# Custom WPF namespace mappings failing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 and converted one of my Visual Studio 2008 WPF projects over for testing.  While the project builds and runs correctly, the VS Designer cannot handle the custom namespace mappings I have giving the error:

> Assembly must be specified for XAML files that are not part of a project. Reopen this XAML file after adding it to a project, close this file and reopen it using the project it is associated with, or modify the clr-namespace to include the name of the assembly.

The namespaces in question are part of the project.  Visual Studio 2008 had no problems with the XAML.  So I created a new blank WPF project called `Test1` with the namespace being `Test1`.  I then edited the generated MainWindow.xaml to add a single mapping for `local`:

```
<Window x:Class="Test1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid />
</Window>
```

This gives the same error.  And, amazingly, Google reports no results for the error!  I tried a few variations such as appending `;assembly=` or `;assembly=Test1`, but that did not help.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?  If nothing, I'd greatly appreciate suggestions for why this may be failing.

**Edit:** As per the comments, it turns out that this only occurs when the project is opened from a networked share.  It does not occur if the project is opened on a local drive.  I would like, however, to be able to open it on the network share so I'm going to leave the question open.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm unable to reproduce this problem. It sounds like the problem isn't your xmlns, though, but rather that for some reason VS thinks your .xaml isn't part of the project.

Comment: Thank you for trying to duplicate it JustABill.  Between your test and the lack of that error on Google, it looks pretty evident that VS2010 is likely damaged in some way or some other problem specific to this development system.

Comment: I ran a successful repair on Visual Studio 2010 and it did not resolve the situation.

Comment: The problem is not with the installation Visual Studio 2010.  I just loaded up the same project using the local drive path (D:\...) instead of a UNC path (\\SERVER\D\...) and it works fine.  Additionally, I get the `You should only open projects from a trustworthy source. The project file 'project' may have come from a location that isn’t fully trusted.` warning when using the UNC path.  

I've verified that I am owner and that I have all necessary permissions.  This was created locally so I can't "unblock" it per various blogs regarding that warning.  I'll continue to investigate.

Comment: It turns out that this problem is not related to the "trustworthy source" issue.  I managed to fix that by reapplying CasPol.exe permissions to my UNC paths (apparently installing VS2010 either reset them or I needed to reapply them with the new .NET 4.0 CasPol.exe, which I also did.  The warning then went away but the problem did not.  It refuses to work unless I use a local drive path.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue problems when remote debugging to a machine, XAML is being filled with errors.  Seems like a bug. Anybody raised an issue with Microsoft? Thats when setting a remote output path, and specifying to debug to a remote machine.

Comment: I have the same problem with VS 2010 SP1 and no UNC paths.

Answer (score 7):

Neil Allen is right. Map the folder as drive and all will be fine.
How to map:
http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-map-a-drive-in-windows/

Answer (score 5):

I’ve had the same problem but I found using a mapped drive letter instead of the UNC path works for me.

Regards

Neil Allen

Answer (score 2):

There is a Connect issue regarding this.  In the workarounds is a link to something you can try to get this going:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/568464/wpf-project-on-a-network-share-with-clr-namespace#details

This is a direct link to the workaround;  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252.aspx

Comment: Thanks Andy.  I'll investigate this workaround sometime soon as I'd like to close this question.  Mapping as a network drive was never an acceptable workaround as many of us know.

Comment: I'd be interested if this fixes the problem as I described it for anyone.  I added `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />` to my devenv.exe.config under `configuration/runtime` (*note: the text editor must be run with admin privileges*) and converted my test project to .NET 4.0, but it hasn't changed the error.

Answer (score 2):

Just to sum up all the answers on this post because this problem was also a pain for me, and I managed to solve it the following way.

First of all, the problem comes from the fact that the project is not on a local drive which creates some issues within the Visual Studio environment.

To solve the problem:

1. Make sure that the project is opened using a mapped drive (like `P:/Projects/.../mySolution.sln`). Be careful, this means that mapping the drive is not sufficient; you have to open it **from** the mapped path (from a file explorer windows using the mapped drive). If you keep loading it using the "recent projects" menu in VS, the path will still be absolute.
2. Modify the development environment config file called `devenv.exe.config` and add `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />` in the section `configuration/runtime`. This file is located on the drive VS is installed on.

It's most likely that if you encounter this problem, you're working in an enterprise environment where you might have restricted access to the local hard drive which means that you have to ask the IT infrastructure department to make the changes for you.

Finally, I'd like to add that you'd also encounter problems with Unit Test projects if you do not use this tweak.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem happened to some in our company because we were using a network share for each developer.

The problem did not happen to those that were using a mapped network drive with saved password for reboots.

It may be something with the domain or the environment ... and VS bad handling of that?

Answer (score 0):

The network path was the culprit in my case.